# Hide / show elements external page inside iframe javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 HTML pages
1- index.html
2- test.html
now the operation
1- I add ifram in the index.html page the iframe src is test.html and I add hideimg button
2- inside test.html I have div which inlude image
how can I hide the image by click button hideimg

index.html

```
<div>
  <div><button onclick="hideimg()">Hideimg</button></div>
  <iframe class="testiframe" src="./test.html"></iframe>
</div>
<script>
  function hideimg() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("testiframe");
  elmnt[0].style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

test.html

```
<H1>Test Hide</H1>
<div class="hideClass">
     <img class="imgClass" width="100px" height="100px" src="./images/covid19.PNG">
</div>
```

Comment: Is it really an *external* page, on a different domain or with content that you don't control?

Comment: Have you tried this class element to hide?   `var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("hideClass");
  elmnt[0].style.display = "none";`

Comment: @Bergi
its all in same domain there is nothing external

Comment: @JesperMartinez
I test something like this its not working
'   var iframe=document.getElementsByClassName("testiframe");
    var elmnt = testiframe.getElementsByClassName("hideClass");
    elmnt[0].style.display = "none";'

Comment: @beginnerphp You'll want to use [`testiframe.contentDocument.getElements…`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) for that

Comment: its working just get the frame by getElementById 
    <iframe id="myFrame" class="testiframe" src="./test.html"></iframe> 
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("hideClass")[0];
elmnt.style.display = "none";